# How to save data on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, save

I want store some date into iPhone in my program，but when I delete my program from iPhone the data should be still in iPhone. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can save data to iPhone permanently using Apps. Once you delete your apps, all related settings and files will be removed.

Alternatively, you can add photos, contacts & notes to users' iPhone.

Comment: please read iOS Developer manual in Apple website, or Google it. It's not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

is your iphone jailbroken? which programme are you referring to? The programmes are usually deleted together with their internal Documents folder, aparet from application executable and dependencies. Custom user programs are not allowed to access any other system or application's space. Hence the reason why there exists so many web related iPhone apps. Why don't you upload it and sync it with some online web service/storage instead to persist this date data you've got?